# Android (C#) -- Service for incoming udp-broadcasts

Tags: c#, android, service, broadcast, wakelock

I'm pretty new to Android programming that's why I need your advice.

**Current Situation:**
I built an Android application (C#) aswell as a regular Server application (C++) which runs on a Raspberry Pi. Both programs communicate via UDP. At the moment that the Server application receives a signal it sends out a broadcast message which the Android application is listening for. Everything works just fine to the moment that the Android device falls asleep/goes idle which leads to my question.

**Question:**
How can I accomplish that the Android applications' listener still works, when the device falls asleep? I do not expect any solutions but any kind of advice so I don't waste time with wrong approaches.

**Research:**
- I read about and tried services that will keep running in the background but the service also stopped as the device went to sleep.
- I read about Broadcast Receivers which allow the application/service to get further information of the system.
- I read about WAKELOCK which allows me to keep the CPU alive, but for my purpose it should be up 'all the time' and that would drain to much energy.

**Code that I would like to run in the background:**

```
public void AsyncReceive()
{
    // ...
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        while (this.isActive)
        { 
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1];
            DatagramPacket incoming = new DatagramPacket(buffer,  
            buffer.Length);

            try
            {
                sock.Receive(incoming);
            }
            catch (...)
            {
                // Exception handling goes here...
            }

            // Communicate with the Android application
            this.FireBroadCastReceivedEvent();
        }
    });
}
```

**Edit**
I also need to notice the application about incoming messages (@the 'FireBroadCastReceivedEvent()' part of the code). What would be a good way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I think you must read this link : https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/index.html

Hope you find what are you looking for.